# Is there a specific way to reference external CSS style sheets in the play framework?

Tags: css, playframework

I know there is a special way for Javascript. The one for CSS I'm using is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/stack.css")' />
```

I tried using src alternatively and it still didnt work. I tested using the styles in the head of my HTML and it was fine, but as soon as I moved it over to the external it didn't work anymore.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But did you forget the '@' character ? href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/stack.css")'

Comment: so I add the answer so that you could validate it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to include the @ symbol in your 'href='

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/stack.css")' />
```

Also, be sure to have your .css files located in your /public/stylesheets/ directory so that Play can reference them.

Comment: If it works as you intend you should mark the answer as accepted to show that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand your question. But did you forget the '@' character ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/stack.css")' />
```